# Remove a string pattern and symbols from string

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to clean up a string from the phrase `"not"` and hashtags(`#`). *(I also have to get rid of spaces and capslock and return them in arrays, but I got the latter three taken care of.)*

Expectation:

```
"not12345"       #=> ["12345"]
"   notabc  "    #=> ["abc"]
"notone, nottwo" #=> ["one", "two"]
"notCAPSLOCK"    #=> ["capslock"]
"##doublehash"   #=> ["doublehash"]
"h#a#s#h"        #=> ["hash"]
"#notswaggerest" #=> ["swaggerest"]
```

This is the code I have

```
def some_method(string)
    string.split(", ").map{|n| n.sub(/(not)/,"").downcase.strip}
end
```

All of the above test does what I need to do except for the hash ones. I don't know how to get rid of the hashes; I have tried modifying the regex part: `n.sub(/(#not)/)`, `n.sub(/#(not)/)`, `n.sub(/[#]*(not)/)` to no avail. How can I make Regex to remove `#`?

Comment: Woops! Typo there. Thanks for noticing! You are correct. It's supposed to be ["hash"]. I will edit it. Thanks @sln!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr = ["not12345", "   notabc", "notone, nottwo", "notCAPSLOCK",
       "##doublehash:", "h#a#s#h", "#notswaggerest"].

arr.flat_map { |str| str.downcase.split(',').map { |s| s.gsub(/#|not|\s+/,"") } }
  #=> ["12345", "abc", "one", "two", "capslock", "doublehash:", "hash", "swaggerest"]
```

When the block variable `str` is set to `"notone, nottwo"`,

```
s = str.downcase
  #=> "notone, nottwo" 
a = s.split(',')
  #=> ["notone", " nottwo"] 
b = a.map { |s| s.gsub(/#|not|\s+/,"") }
  #=> ["one", "two"]
```

Because I used [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map), `"one"` and `"two"` are added to the array being returned. When `str #=> "notCAPSLOCK"`,

```
s = str.downcase
  #=> "notcapslock" 
a = s.split(',')
  #=> ["notcapslock"] 
b = a.map { |s| s.gsub(/#|not|\s+/,"") }
  #=> ["capslock"]
```

Comment: seems "one,two" should be ["one","two"] base on the expectations.

Comment: Thanks, @engineersmnky, I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more solution that uses a different technique of capturing what you want rather than dropping what you don't want: (for the most part)

```
a = ["not12345", "   notabc", "notone, nottwo", 
 "notCAPSLOCK", "##doublehash:","h#a#s#h", "#notswaggerest"]
a.map do |s|
     s.downcase.delete("#").scan(/(?<=not)\w+|^[^not]\w+/)
end 
#=> [["12345"], ["abc"], ["one", "two"], ["capslock"], ["doublehash"], ["hash"], ["swaggerest"]]
```

Had to delete the `#` because of `h#a#s#h` otherwise delete could have been avoided with a regex like `/(?<=not|^#[^not])\w+/`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to solve your problem. I tested and it works for all of your test cases.

```
/^\s*#*(not)*/
```

- `^` means match start of string
- `\s*` matches any space at the start
- `#*` matches 0 or more #
- `(not)*` matches the phrase "not" zero or more times.

*Note: this regex won't work for cases where "not" comes before "#", such as `not#hash` would return `#hash`*

Answer (score 1):

Ruby regular expressions [allow comments](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Free-Spacing+Mode+and+Comments), so to match the octothorpe (`#`) you can escape it:

```
"#foo".sub(/\#/, "") #=> "foo"
```

Comment: you don't need to escape `#` in a normal regex expression. The time you need to do that is when you use the `\x` option, which ignores all white spaces and allow use of comments with `#`

Comment: The answer is incorrect. As @davidhu2000 says, only when the `x` flag is used. `"#foo".sub(/#/, "") # => "foo"` works without escaping.

Comment: The answer is _NOT_ incorrect. The pound sign can be escaped to mean a literal in either expanded //x or not // regexes.

Comment: But you did say, "...you have to escape it...". Is that not incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Fun problem because it can use the most common string functions in Ruby:

```
result = values.map do |string|
 string.strip      # Remove spaces in front and back.
   .tr('#','')     # Transform single characters. In this case remove #
   .gsub('not','') # Substitute patterns
   .split(', ')    # Split into arrays.
end

p result #=>[["12345"], ["abc"], ["one", "two"], ["CAPSLOCK"], ["doublehash"], ["hash"], ["swaggerest"]]
```

I prefer this way rather than a regexp as it is easy to understand the logic of each line.